# Why can't I connect to my oracle database using VBScript

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, vbscript, vba

I want to connect to databsae using VBscript. Installed oracle Client and odbc drivers as suggested by couple of sites. Copied vbscript from http://qtpromania.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-connect-to-oracle-database-using.html. I have oracle 11g express edition installed. 
Wanted to run the code with local database first and den try to connect server side database. But i am not able to connect to database when i execute my vbscript. Is it something that i am missing. Please suggest.

' Trying first with local Database. Later i want to connect server side 'Database
        HOST = "localhost"
        PORT = "1521"
        SID = "XE"
        USER = "system"
        PASSWORD = "system"

```
    Srvname="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
    "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
    "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
    "(HOST="& HOST &")(PORT="& PORT &"))" & _
    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID="& SID &"))); uid="& USER &";pwd="& PASSWORD &";"

    Set Rec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set conn=Createobject("ADODB.Connection")


    MsgBox "Before"
    MsgBox Srvname
    'Cannot get past this point.Its like I cannot connect to the path 
    ' I have installed oracle client recently.

    conn.open Srvname

    If conn.State = "1" Then 'Check connection
      MsgBox "Connected to DB"
    Else
      MsgBox "NOT connected to DB"
    End If

SQLSec="select Age from Persons where Name like 'A%'" 'SQL statement
   Rec.open SQLSec,conn
   Age=Rec.fields("AGE") 'AGE is the name of the column
   Rec.Close

MsgBox Age
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run this? What error do you get? What have you installed locally - you mention the client, but do you have the server software locally, is the listener running on localhost:1521, have you created a database, and is it running?

Comment: 1. My Vbcript end abruptly at that point after giving the my MsgBox 'connection string' as popup. 2. I dont get any error. 3. I have oracle 11g databsae installed. Dis https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/9212a04b-ae1d-4a7f-87ba-cfa336898565/connect-to-oracle-db-using-vbscript?forum=ITCG suggested to have oracle client and odbc drivers installed to achieve my task. 3. By default we have a local database when we install oracle 11g - Dats the database i am trying to access. 4. Yes my listerner is running on 1521. 5. Yes my database is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Try connectstring like this:

```
Srvname="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; Server=""" & _
    "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
    "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
    "(HOST="& HOST &")(PORT="& PORT &"))" & _
    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID="& SID &")))""; uid="& USER &";pwd="& PASSWORD &";"
```

Which Oracle Client do you have installed - 64 bit or 32 bit?

Check if ODBC driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" is installed. On my machine it exist only for 32 bit, however by default VBscript runs in 64 bit Environment. This does not match.

In order to check 32 bit ODBC drivers run `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`
For 64 bit ODBC driver run `c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Client - 64 bit, and i am not getting "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" in both of the dialog box  list. I am getting MS Access dBaseDrivers, Oracle in XE, MS Access Driver

Comment: @SBose, Then try `Driver={Oracle in XE}` instead of `Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}` and `DBQ=...` instead of `Server=...`

Comment: Do i need to have ms Visual Studio installed?

Comment: @SBose, no Visual Studio is not needed.

Comment: Can u suggest me where would i get "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle"? i am not getting it..

Comment: When you look at Microsoft [ODBC Driver for Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [Data Access Technologies Road Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx) you see it has been deprecated. Unless you don't have any old setup file it seems to be difficult to get it legally.

Comment: Why do you insist to use the ODBC driver from Microsoft? The driver from Oracle works as well and is free of charge.